# How to use jQuery .get() to store results in separate elements

Tags: jquery, arrays

Demonstrated in this codepen: https://codepen.io/alvintrilliams/pen/bWJVLY

I am using jQuery to get a list of values of checked checkboxes in a "set".

It works, though not if there are multiple "sets" of checkboxes.

In the codepen, if I check off 1 and B, it shows:

> Numbers: 1,B. Letters: 1,B.

Should be:

> Numbers: 1. Letters: B.

I'm having trouble understanding how to have the variable store 2 (or more) sets of results, and then displaying the result within the corresponding element.

jQuery:

```
$(".checkboxes").on('click', function() { 
  var boxes = ($("input:checked").map(function() {
    return this.value;
  }).get().join(","));
  $('.checkboxes').find(".checked").text(boxes);
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="checkboxes">

  Numbers: <span class="checked"></span>
  <br>
  <input name="numbers" type="checkbox" value="1"/>1
  <input name="numbers" type="checkbox" value="2"/>2
  <br>

  Letters: <span class="checked"></span>
  <br>
  <input name="letters" type="checkbox" value="A"/>A
  <input name="letters" type="checkbox" value="B"/>B

</div>
```

Comment: So the desired output could be `Numbers: 1, 2. Letters: A, B.` if all checkboxes were checked?

Comment: Correct. Instead, my current example has "Numbers: 1, 2, A, B" and "Letters: 1, 2, A, B"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you map over all of the checkboxes, and then store the same result in all of the spans.

The following code works for the HTML structure shown by iterating over the output spans and using `.nextUntil()` to find just the checked checkboxes that follow *before* the next span or end of the container div:

```js
$(".checkboxes").on('click', function() {
  $(".checked").each(function() {
    var boxes = $(this).nextUntil("span")
      .filter("input:checked")
      .map(function() { return this.value })
      .get()
      .join(",");
    $(this).text(boxes);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkboxes">
  Numbers: <span class="checked"></span>
  <br>
  <input name="numbers" type="checkbox" value="1"/>1
  <input name="numbers" type="checkbox" value="2"/>2
  <br>

  Letters: <span class="checked"></span>
  <br>
  <input name="letters" type="checkbox" value="A"/>A
  <input name="letters" type="checkbox" value="B"/>B
</div>
```

Using `.nextUntil()` like that is a little brittle though, because changes to the HTML structure could easily break it. It would be better if you could modify the HTML to associate the spans with their checkboxes more directly, perhaps by adding `data-checks="numbers"` (or `="letters"`), or just by adding a wrapper element around each group and then adding the click handlers to the wrappers and only processing the current wrapper's contents:

```js
$(".cbwrapper").on('click', function() {
  var wrapper = $(this);
  var boxes = wrapper.find("input:checked")
    .map(function() { return this.value })
    .get()
    .join(",");
  wrapper.find(".checked").text(boxes);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkboxes">
  <div class="cbwrapper">
    Numbers: <span class="checked"></span>
    <br>
    <input name="numbers" type="checkbox" value="1"/>1
    <input name="numbers" type="checkbox" value="2"/>2
    <br>
  </div>
  <div class="cbwrapper">
    Letters: <span class="checked"></span>
    <br>
    <input name="letters" type="checkbox" value="A"/>A
    <input name="letters" type="checkbox" value="B"/>B
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that this also makes the HTML easier to read in a general sense.

Comment: Brilliant! I applied your second solution (wrapper for each set) and it works perfectly. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Select checkboxes by name

```js
$("input[type=checkbox]").on('change', function() { 
  var name = $(this).prop("name"),
      boxes = "";
  $("input[name="+name+"]:checked").each(function(i){
    boxes += (i>0?", ":"") + this.value;
  });
  $(".checked").eq(name=="numbers"?0:1).text(boxes);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkboxes">

  Numbers: <span class="checked"></span>
  <br>
  <input name="numbers" type="checkbox" value="1"/>1
  <input name="numbers" type="checkbox" value="2"/>2
  <br>

  Letters: <span class="checked"></span>
  <br>
  <input name="letters" type="checkbox" value="A"/>A
  <input name="letters" type="checkbox" value="B"/>B

</div>
```